# Remove inner padding from td

Tags: html, css

I've got a table row which has 3 columns now. text text image(with cellspan=2 and rowspan=2)

How can I remove that padding from the right inside the td.
Basically I want to push the image to the left.

img is inside td too

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add the current html of the table?

Comment: well, it's from old outlook email signature and the code is very messy. I think I can't. Too much lines

Comment: Have you tried using cell-padding and/or cell-spacing attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to effect the entire table, you can remove explicit width from all `<td>`s, and then the text will take as much space as it actually needs.

If you want to effect only one row, you can put the text and the image inside the same `<td colspan=2>` instead of two separate `<td>`s

Comment: I've just remade it manually in that stupid outlook. But I've also made a search and found this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp I think your answer is correct :) ty

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is, Verticle- align try to change the values as you wanted

example code

```
vertical-align:baseline;
```

assigned generally applies to common html elements. with this change, Now everything works as supposed to.